# 'message' is a 'variable' but used like a 'method'

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

Learning C# and trying to create a quick game and I am getting the error message 'message' is a 'variable' but used like a 'method'. Created a blank string called message and have defined it below. Following a tutorial on Microsoft Virtual academy.

```
 using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;

    namespace PrizeGame
    {
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello, you're going to play a game"+
                "Pick a number between 1 and 10, Type it and press enter.");
            string userValue = Console.ReadLine();
            string message="";
            string noWin ="Sorry, you didn't win anything :(. On the"+
            "other hand you helped me with my project, thanks!";
            if (userValue == "1")
            {
                message(noWin);
            }
            else if (userValue=="2")
            {
               message("Congratulations, you won a penny! Also, thanks for"+
                "helping me with my project!");
            }
            else if(userValue=="3")
            {
                message(noWin);
            }
            else if(userValue=="3")
            {
                message(noWin);
            }
            else if(userValue=="4")
            {
            message("Congratulations, you won 20 pence! Also, thanks for"+
                "helping me with my project!");
            }
            else if(userValue=="5")
            {
                message(noWin);
            }
            else if(userValue=="6")
                {
                    message(noWin);
                }
            else if(userValue=="7")
            {
                message ("Congratulations, you just won the top prize, £1!!"+
                "Also, thanks for helping me with my project.");
            }
            else if (userValue=="8")
            {
                message(noWin);
            }
            else if (userValue=="9")
            {
                message(noWin);
            }
            else if (userValue=="10")
            {
                message(noWin);
            }
            else
            {
                message("Sorry I couldn't understand what you wrote"+
                "make sure you use a number between 1 and 10");
            }
            Console.WriteLine(message);
            Console.ReadLine(),;


        }
    }

    }
`
```

Comment: `message(noWin)` makes no sense.

Comment: Probably you are trying to assign a value to the `message` variable. Use `=` instead of `()`.

Comment: What are you expecting this code to do? What do you expect `message(noWin)` to do?

Comment: _"Learning C# and I am getting the error message"_ - no offense, please follow a tutorial on the basics on C# syntax and learn to search the web for compiler errors you get. Don't outsource this to Stack Overflow.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about using Stack Overflow as a compiler.

Comment: Also this would not compile because you have a comma in 'Console.ReadLine(),;'

Comment: Use

message = "your string"

instead of

message("your string")

because it is a variable, not a method!

Comment: @Spikolynn Thanks, noticed that before!

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Sorted now, wanted it to just be a short cut so I don't have to type the same long sentence every time

Comment: You cannot just invent your own syntax. You ought to edit the question to explain what you expected the code to do.

Answer (score 2):

You are declaring a string variable called message. You can't call it using method notation.

Do this

```
message = "Congratulations, you won a penny! Also, thanks for"+"helping me with my project!";
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a function call, what you have:

```
message(noWin);
```

This is a string assignment:

```
message = noWin;
```

OR

```
message += noWin; //appended to the end
```

You want one of the latter to assign the value to the variable, for use later; C# doesn't use the () notation for that.  If you were expecting message to be an array, then you need:

```
string[] message;
```

However, it would be much easier to do:

```
var messages = new List<string>();
messages.Add(noWin);
```

Comment: Thanks, used the first string assignment!

Answer (score 0):

I've looked at your code, and in .NET, you have either a method, or a variable, a variable is called by it's name, while a function or function is called by it's name, followed by (). In between those brackets can be the parameters for the function.

Your message doesn't have anything while your noWin is a string/text.

When you want to display that string you should use:

```
Console.WriteLine(noWin);
```

I hope that it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you supposed to use as below:

```
MessageBox.Show(noWin);
```

And in your case using switch statement instead of if else if would be more readable. 
Hope it helps.